# Integration with ForgeRock

Tags: asp.net-core, forgerock, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

ForgeRock always returns HTTP 500 error for SSO. I am using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 for the binding (redirect) in my asp.net core application as my IDP for forgeRock and following steps mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2)

This is the SAML Auth Request sent out

```html
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
     xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
     xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
     ID="_f149a6ed-298a-4d41-951f-3817a5e3f7ae"
     Version="2.0"
     IssueInstant="2020-08-15T21:53:37.9212248Z" 
    Destination="http://dev.mytest.com/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/RRC/idp" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:60017/General/Account/AssertionConsumerService">
       <saml2:Issuer>http://dev.mytest.com:80/sso</saml2:Issuer>
       <saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID> https://localhost:60017</saml2:NameID></saml2:Subject>
       <saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" 
                  Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" />
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

2 questions, I have been asked from the ForgeRock

1. Can I use the samlp and saml tags instead of saml2p and saml2 tags in the request SAML
2. Binding is not mentioned in the auth request SAMLf

Error Message

[HTTP 500 Error from ForgeRock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKN7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little in doubt about your question. If you are asking about XML namespace names. It is not possible to change XML namespace names in the XML the [ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) component generates.

It is probably correct to use a redirect binding.

You are sending ' https://localhost:60017' in the NameID tag with a space `<saml2:NameID> https://localhost:60017</saml2:NameID>`. It looks wrong? It should be the username for the user you want to be logged in.

Comment: Thanks @Anders, oroginally we had the nameID tag as "TestUser" then suggestion was to change the localhost url so I modified. I tried but that still it did not help. The other question is in the SAML Request I do not see the binding Protocol at all. For example like this  ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"

Comment: The SAML 2.0 binding is mostly about using either HTTP GET or HTTP POST with some defined parameters and generally not about the XML. However, there is some differences regarding signing.

Comment: The issue was resolved, the issuer id was wrong with the SAML auth request after correcting that and IDp fixed the issue on their side, things are working fine. Thank you!